# Why can't I remove an object from a class?

Tags: python, class, data-structures

I tried to remove the banana from the method **remove_by_value**, but it was unable to remove.

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    def insert_at_end(self, data):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(data, None)
            return

        itr = self.head        
        while itr.next:
            itr = itr.next
        itr.next = Node(data, None)

    def insert_values(self, data_list):
        self.head = None
        for data in data_list:
            self.insert_at_end(data)
    
    def remove_by_value(self,data):
        itr = self.head
        if itr is None:
            return

        if itr.data == data:
            itr.next = itr.next
            return

        while itr:
            if itr.next.data == data:
                itr.next = itr.next.next
                break
            itr = itr.next
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ll = LinkedList()
    ll.insert_values(["banana","mango","grapes","orange"])
    ll.print() # from method to show all object.
    ll.remove_by_value2("banana")
    ll.print()
```

**output:**

- banana=>mango=>grapes=>orange=>
- banana=>mango=>grapes=>orange=>

Comment: Because `itr.next = itr.next` does nothing.

Comment: Also, please give us code that actually runs. Your code does not run, because there is no method `remove_by_value2`, no method `print` and we're missing the `Node` class. We prefer a [mre].

Comment: Next, try to get your wording right: you're not removing an object from a class, you're removing an object (of type Node) from another object (of type LinkedList)

Comment: Linked-list methods are a lot simpler if `self.head` always refers to a dummy node, so that `self.head.next is None` indicates an empty list. It lets you get rid of a lot of special cases.

Comment: Thank @ThomasWeller But output is not change. ;-;

Comment: ```
def print(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print('Linked list is empty')

        itr = self.head
        llstr = ''
        while itr:
            llstr += str(itr.data) + '=>'
            itr = itr.next
        print(llstr)
```

Answer (score 0):

please look here at the part of the remove node:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_data_structure/python_linked_lists.htm

this is how you suppose to implement a linked list in python :)
let me know if you have more questions about it